# how to run both java and python command in a shell script

Tags: java, python, shell, cron

I have to automate certain tests daily using cron job. I specify my shell script in my cron job. First, I have to first start my spring-boot application. I do that using the `java -jar spring-boot-app.jar` command. Then I need to execute a `python` script after starting the `spring-boot` app. I've put both these 2 commands in a shell script. But the problem is the python script is not being run, after starting the spring-boot app from the shell script. How do I start the python script too? I tried opening a new terminal using `gnome-terminal` in my script, but this command doesn't work in a remote machine. How do I start both the spring-boot app and the python command?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar spring-boot-app.jar &
python /path/to/your/script.py
```

Comment: If the Python script needs to connect to the Java app, and this solution ends up starting the Python script too soon (before the Java app is ready), then you might want to insert a sleep command like `sleep 1` (the 1 is the number of seconds to sleep) in between the java and python lines in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer above by UtLox will resolve your problem, because the "&" at the end will run your Spring Boot application in the background